# boost equivalent to windows mutex

Tags: c++, windows, boost

In boost land on Mac OS, following code will deadlock itself:

```
boost::mutex m;

m.lock();
m.lock();
```

the same goes with

```
boost::mutex m;

boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
```

in Windows land, the same thread can get a Win32 mutex as often as it wants, as long as the release count is the same. I need the exact behavior with a boost sync object.

Comment: The correct term is "reentrant". So if what you say is true, on MacOS the boost::mutex isn't reentrant, while on Windows it is.

Comment: thanks, "reentrant" was the word I was missing. And yeah, seems so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a [boost::recursive_mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/doc/html/recursive_mutex.html):

> The recursive_mutex class uses a Recursive locking strategy, so attempts to recursively lock a recursive_mutex object succeed and an internal "lock count" is maintained. Attempts to unlock a recursive_mutex object by threads that don't own a lock on it result in undefined behavior.

Note that the [boost::mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/doc/html/mutex.html):

> The mutex class uses an Unspecified locking strategy, so attempts to recursively lock a mutex object or attempts to unlock one by threads that don't own a lock on it result in undefined behavior. This strategy allows implementations to be as efficient as possible on any given platform.

In Computer Science the recursive mutex is called [Reentrant Mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex):

> In computer science, a reentrant mutex is a mutual exclusion, recursive lock mechanism. In a reentrant mutex, the same thread can acquire the lock multiple times. However, the lock must be released the same number of times or else other threads will be unable to acquire the lock

Comment: thx, you saved my day. Porting from WinAPI to boost can sometime be so awefull.

Comment: @MartinSchlott I always had problems navigating the documentation of Boost :-)

Answer (score 1):

try to use a recursive mutex : As boost::mutex is not recursive, we need to use its recursive version `boost::recursive_mutex`